# Cannot use voice command through Google Search Bar microphone icon

Tags: app-widgets, google-assistant, voice-command, google-search

I have a Pixel 7. I have typically been able to just go to the search bar on the bottom screen of my phone and say set an alarm and it always set an alarm. Now it's sending me to a website.

Is there any way to take it back to just setting the alarm?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, it's not possible to access Google Assistant anymore through the microphone icon from the Google Search bar widget.** Users have to use alternative triggers like saying "Hey Google", long-pressing the home button, squeezing the phone (on select Pixel), or long-pressing the power button (on select Pixel).

There were big changes in January 2024 related to Google Assistant, including the shortcut from the microphone icon. As Google stated in [Changes we’re making to Google Assistant](https://blog.google/products/assistant/google-assistant-update-january-2024/),

> We’re also bringing you a more consistent experience within the Google app: The microphone icon will now trigger Search results in response to your queries, which is its most popular use case. You can continue to activate Assistant as you always have: Just say “Hey Google” or long press on the home or power button (on select phones) on [Android](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7172657) [...]. But you’ll no longer be able to use the microphone icon in the Search bar to complete actions like “turn on the lights” or “send a message.” This includes the microphone in the Pixel Search bar, which will now activate Voice Search instead of Assistant. [...]

When the user taps the microphone icon for the first time after the update, there will be a pop-up that states

> **Access to Google Assistant has moved**
>
> The microphone button on the search bar now opens Google Voice Search instead of Assistant.
>
> You can still access Assistant with "Hey Google" or if you press & hold the power button to seat alarms, send messages, and more anytime.
>
> [image]